# How to Create a Configuration Section That Contains a Collection

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, system.configuration

There is a great question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958054/how-to-create-a-configuration-section-that-contains-a-collection-of-collections) that illustrates how to create a custom configuration section that is able to parse configuration of the following form into .Net objects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="CustomConfigSection" type="ConfigTest.CustomConfigSection,ConfigTest" />
  </configSections>

  <CustomConfigSection>
    <ConfigElements>
      <ConfigElement key="Test1" />
      <ConfigElement key="Test2" />
    </ConfigElements>
  </CustomConfigSection>

</configuration>
```

My question is, does anyone know how to create the same custom configuration section without the `ConfigElements` element?  For example, one that would parse the following `CustomConfigSection` element in place of the one shown above:

```
  <CustomConfigSection>
    <ConfigElement key="Test1" />
    <ConfigElement key="Test2" />
  </CustomConfigSection>
```

The issue that I have is that it appears that the type `CustomConfigSection` needs to inherit from both [ConfigurationSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ConfigurationElementCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which of course is not possible in C#.  The other approach I have found requires me to implement [IConfigurationSectionHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.iconfigurationsectionhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is deprecated as of .Net v2.  Does anyone know how to accomplish the desired result?  Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to inherit from both ConfigurationSection and ConfigurationElementCollection.  Instead, define your config section like this:

```
public class CustomConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    public MyConfigElementCollection ConfigElementCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return (MyConfigElementCollection)base[""];
        }
    }
}
```

And your config element collection:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MyConfigElement), AddItemName = "ConfigElement"]
public class MyConfigElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new MyConfigElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");

        return ((MyConfigElement)element).key;
    }
}
```

And config element itself:

```
public class MyConfigElement: ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("key", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["key"];
        }
    }   
}
```